# Consistent cluster labels after several runs of algorithm

Tags: clustering

When running a clustering algorithm several times (e.g. k-means) I get different assignment of labels for the same clusters (that is understandable since labels are just symbolic). Is it possible to get all the time the same labels for the same data points after running clustering algorithm again and again?

Answer (score 1):

Compare each cluster with each other cluster.
Reassign the same label by best match.
There is no better way to do this.

However, **do not expect k-means results to be too similar**. In particular on difficult data sets, results tend to vary a *lot*. At some point, there is no use in trying to make labels "consistent" when the clusters are 90% different on the "best" match. In the end **k-means is a randomized algorithm, so expect it to return very different results** (that is a strength, not a bug).

Answer (score 0):

In most statisticals softwares/programming languages (R,Python,C#...), you can **set the seed to a fixed number** so that the random number generator of your program produces the same sequence of random numbers at each run. In R, this looks like `set.seed(12)`, where 12 is your seed.

Random number generator are not that random, what they usually do is take DateTime.Now.Milliseconds as a seed, and start generating random number from there, explaining the non reproducible results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was more interested not in a technical solution but rather in the method of association. I know that there are some methods that allow to associate cluster labels, but unfortunately dont know which of them are effective.